sql plus no tabula las consultas
Estoy usando SQL*Plus y no consigo que tabule bien las consultas. A la consulta:
select table_name, tablespace_name from all_tables where tablespace_name = 'system';

La muestra así:

Cuando debería mostrarla así:

¿A qué puede deberse?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

sql*plus es un programa de la consola y por esto está limitado. Te recomiendo usar un programa con GUI en vez. Por ejemplo, Oracle SQL Developer (que es gratis).
Lo que vez es que tu consola tiene una anchura limitada (por ejemplo, para 80 caracteres), pero tu consulta resulta en una tabla de más caracteres. O mejor dicho, sql*plus facilita espacio para valores largas, y así las columnas de la consulta están muy anchas en la consola.
Si quieres usar sql*plus para mostrar un resultado de una consulta, puedes ajustar el programa para tu consulta, es decir fijar que anchos deben ser las columnas y la tabla. Por ejemplo:
sql>column table_name format a20
sql>column tablespace_name format a20

y/o
sql>set linesize 200


Muchas gracias. Efectivamente, eso es lo que he terminado viendo por ahí. Gracias otra vez por tu respuesta.

Si que la está tabulando, pero el problema es que el contenido de cada registro no cabe en una sola línea, por tanto SQL*Plus no tiene de otra que utilizar varias líneas para mostrarlo, en este caso 2.
Y es que SQL*Plus utiliza, en el caso de columnas compuestas de caracteres, el ancho de dicha columna para dimensionarla en el resultado. Puedes hacerte una idea del ancho de cada columna viendo la línea de guiones (----) que coloca debajo del título de la misma.
Así, verás que para la columna table_name, está usando unos 75 caracteres (es lo que logré contar en la imagen).
Tienes varias alternativas para esto:

Puedes traer solo los primeros N caracteres de la columna, usando substr, para hacerla más pequeña.
  select substr(table_name, 1, 30) table_name, tablespace_name from all_tables where tablespace_name = 'system';


Si quieres conservar el ancho de las columnas, puedes ejecutar en una consola de mayor ancho. Esto depende del sistema operativo y la versión de SQL*PLus que utilices, pero regularmente se ajusta al ancho de la consola del sistema:

Puedes cambiar cuántos caracteres se imprimen en una línea física de SQL*Plus, cambiando valor de la variable LINESIZE, así estableces el ancho de la línea a 300 caracteres:
  set linesize 300;

Debes tener en cuenta que, si el ancho de la consola es menor a este, aún podrías ver una línea de SQL*Plus ocupar varias líneas de la consola, pero esto si haría la diferencia, por ejemplo, si usas el comando spool para almacenar la salida en un archivo de texto.

Puedes cambiar el ancho al que se imprimen las columnas de texto, independientemente del ancho que tiene en el conjunto de datos de resultado, utilizando el comando column para establecer un formato AX, dónde X es la longitud. Por ejemplo, para establecer las columna table_name a 30 caracteres:
  column table_name format A30



